# Is it okay and how to upload a commercial lib to maven central?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, nexus

I am developing a paid third party lib for android. I wanted to know how to exclude "sources.jar" and "javadocs.jar" automatic upload to maven.

Is it still okay to upload commercial lib there? I have not found much info related to commercial use.

Edit:
I am using Chris banes gradle script to upload to maven.
https://chris.banes.me/2013/08/27/pushing-aars-to-maven-central/

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of technical and legal requirements.

The [technical requirements](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/requirements.html) include javadoc and sources files to be included.

Generally it is NOT possible to upload commercial libraries. Please [read the terms in detail](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/central-repository-producer-terms.html) and potentially contact a lawyer.

Answer (score 0):

To push libraries to Maven Central here:  http://central.sonatype.org/
you will find all the necessary information.